# aws ec2 connection time out after a successful connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

i have an EC2 instance that is connected to Elastic IP, when I'm using ssh to try and establish a connection the attempt has **succeeded**and i can make changes in the ec2 but after 1min-50min the connection is timed out and only after I stop and then restart the EC2 instance the connection can be re-established.

currently, the security groups allow all the traffic to come and go from SSH, HTTP and HTTPS.

the connection is failing before i even run any of the files.

thanks for the help every one

i tryed:
enable all of the inbound and outbound trafic
used elastic ip so the connection host wont change.

im expecting the connection to be stable for at least some time but it's failing at random times

Comment: The fact that you managed to connect initially means that your network settings are correct. The problem is either due to your Internet connection (try from somewhere else, like home/office/tethered to your phone) or the problem is on the EC2 instance (high CPU, lower memory). Take a look at the Monitoring tab on the EC2 management console to see if there is unusual CPU activity.

Comment: When the connection is mentioned as time-out, are you able to open a new SSH session ?